# Adding Dropbox link on Windows 8.1 desktop

Tags: windows-8.1, shortcuts, desktop, dropbox

I have Windows 8.1.

I use Dropbox for work.

How do I get a shortcut to my Dropbox  on my desktop?

The Dropbox link right now is in my start menu.

I have been unable to find Dropbox anywhere on my PC. If I could,
I could then create a shortcut but I have looked everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

[Install the desktop version](https://www.dropbox.com/install) instead of the app.

Once installed, you will get a login screen and then you will be able to access Dropbox folders from any Windows desktop program. You will also have an icon in your system tray. In Windows 8.1, the app does not allow simple copy and pasting of files or drag and drop. Only the desktop version allows for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you right clic on the Start menu shortcut, then in the lower part of the screen you clic on Open File location you will find the shortcut, just copy and paste it in your desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click, New, Shortcut, and paste:

```
%appdata%\Dropbox\bin\Dropbox.exe /home
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just right click on the Dropbox App in the App Window and pin a shortcut to your taskbar on your desktop? That's what I did.